# kubernetes - "govc: network 'vm network' not found" when deploying cluster

Tags: kubernetes

When downloading kubernetes and attempting to deploy a cluster using -

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=YOUR_PROVIDER; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

I get an error message that states - `govc: network 'VM Network' not found.`

VM Network is a valid network in my environment and I currently have VMs on it, so I know that it works.

I have tried using other networks and haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: kubernetes error]

Answer (score 0):

with all your other GOVC_* environment variables set (things like username, password, etc) try:

```
govc ls -l
```

This should give you a set of resources, one of which should look like:

```
/<your-datacenter>/network
```

After that, running:

```
govc ls -l /<your-datacenter>/network
```

should give you a set of one or more network resources. Choose one and run:

```
export GOVC_NETWORK='/<your-datacenter>/network/<your-network>'
```

then try kube-up again.